# I am trying to steer my steeringWheel(GameObject) but for some reason "steeringWheel.transform.localRotation = localRotation" wont actually update it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

```cs
void Steer()
    {
        foreach(var wheel in wheels)
        {
            if (wheel.axel == Axel.Front)
            {
                var _steerAngle = steerInput * turnSensitivity * maxSteerAngle;
                wheel.wheelCollider.steerAngle = Mathf.Lerp(wheel.wheelCollider.steerAngle, _steerAngle, 0.6f);
            }
        }
        var wheelAngle = steerInput * turnSensitivity * maxSteerAngle;
        
        
        var localRotation = steeringWheel.transform.localRotation;
        localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(localRotation.x, localRotation.y,  localRotation.z + WheelSteeringMove(localRotation.z, wheelAngle));
        steeringWheel.transform.localRotation = localRotation;
    }

    float WheelSteeringMove(float lRSteeringWheel_Z, float wheelAngle)
    {
        var wheelSteerDistance = Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Abs(lRSteeringWheel_Z) - Mathf.Abs(wheelAngle));
        var step = 0f;
        
        if (wheelSteerDistance > 0)
        {
            if (wheelAngle > lRSteeringWheel_Z)
            {
                step = -0.6f;
            }
            else
            {
                step = 0.6f;
            }
        }

        if (wheelSteerDistance < Mathf.Abs(step))
        {
            return wheelSteerDistance;
        }

        return step;
    }
```

[image]

I was trying to turn the steeringwheel (GameObject) till a certain angle for both right(z+ when pressing "d") and left(-z when pressing "a"), and im expecting the localrotation to update.

Comment: Do you call Steer() in Update?

Comment: i tried calling Steer() in lateUpdate and in lUpdate and It still didnt work

Comment: Did you try to use the Y axis instead of the Z?

Comment: i just tried it and it still didn't work.